# Internet not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04

I'm using Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 with uefi dual boot. I had to force shut down Ubuntu after it hanged. Since then internet is not working in ubuntu while everything is fine in windows. Attaching the photos of outputs of some commands I ran to check things.

Looks like my router is connected to the laptop just fine. I can't understand where the problem lies since Windows isn't having any.

Thanks in advance for your help.
[image: ifconfig and route -n]
[image: ping outputs and grep proxy /etc/environment]
[image: nm-tool output part 1]
[image: nm-tool output part 2]

Edit: some more outputs
[image]

Comment: Do you use DNS cache (nscd)?

Comment: Please remove all those screenshots and rather add the code as text to your question and format it as code block!

Comment: @derHugo I would have done that. However, since the internet was not working, I had to type on my phone. Don't have access to these outputs any more. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons why you might get such problems. You are connected to router but not the internet. I will suggest two solutions.

If you have **nscd** installed then try this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

If not then try to release and renew the IP

```
sudo dhclient -r eth0
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Comment: But he IS connected to the internet

Comment: And he's connected through eth0 NOT wireless

Comment: He is connected to the internet true. but if there is IP conflict in the internal network (which we have no information about it) then it might cause problem. He can also use **arp-scan** to give more info but atm let's try to narrow it

Comment: True story :p I have wireless so was trying the command here before posting it :)

Comment: Yeah possible but doesn't feel like ip conflict, he'd have dropped pings and other issues this is consistent DNS problems

Comment: Releasing and renewing the IP worked like a charm. Didn't have to change the DNS. Thank you

Comment: I have a feeling you might be back ;)

Comment: Glad it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your internet is working as show by successful pings to 4.2.2.2.

Whats not working is you DNS translations from google.com to its IP.

You're setting your DNS servers to 64.59.144.93 and 64.59.150.139 are you sure that's correct?

Try

```
nslookup google.com 64.59.144.93
```

and

```
nslookup google.com 64.59.150.139
```

if they don't respond try using public dns servers like

```
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
```

or 8.8.4.4 or 4.2.2.2.

Comment: You are definitely on to something! But the DNS seem fine. Nslookup returns a different list of IP addresses for both dns. Ping gives 0 packet loss for every IP on that list. Even entering them directly to the browser address bar starts Google. However pinging Google still doesn't work.

Comment: Show your `nslookup ubuntu.com`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Added an edit!!

Comment: Do `dig ubuntu.com`  So it'd use whatever DNS it thinks it's suppose to. i'm speculating that it'd try 127.0.0.1 instead of 64.59.144.93